# Adding apple cider vinegar to a solid DIY deodorant

Tags: acid-base, everyday-chemistry

If I wanted to add a bit of apple cider vinegar to my oil based deodorant, to increase antimicrobial properties, would this cause me to need a preservative? My deodorant is not water based, so I don't need a preservative in my formulation currently. I also already use lemon in my recipe.

Comment: Vinegar has a strong odor plus tons of water. Your DIY may smell like Pringles with a vinegar flavor.

Comment: I feel like smelling like strong vinegar is not better than slightly body odor.

Comment: Hope your users don't work in a biology lab. Fruit flies are drawn to vinegar which is characteristic of rotting fruit.

Comment: How we shall know if something antimicrobial than ask for preservatives? It seems a contradictions, though preservatives is whatever preserves. I would buy a commercial stick and cook something nice instead ;-)

Comment: Hahaha! Guys, I know how vinegar smells and it was just a thought to add a small amount into my formulation. I have a successful formulation now that people love, but my other formulation seems a bit less effective since I removed the baking soda from it due to some being very sensitive to the baking soda. I'm looking for something else to add in. Apple cider vinegar does smell pretty bad by itself. So I was going to play around. I don't want to have to start adding in preservatives though. Thank you for your answers so far though.